# C++ File Handling - Output does not match Input

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I'm in an introductory C++ class and I am having a strange issue with reading from an input file. I have a text file named "inputFile.txt" that only contains the value of 5. The following code is meant to open the file, read the value of 5 and assign it to the variable 'a' then print the value of 'a' to the console. No matter what I do, the code always prints out "528".

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a;

   //create and open file
   ifstream input;
   input.open("inputFile.txt");

   //read value of 5 from file and assign to a
   input >> a;

   //print value of a       
   cout << a << endl;

   system("PAUSE");
}
```

I hate to ask this question because it's so basic that I feel I MUST be overlooking something extremely simple. However, I am at a complete loss right now and no amount of web searches has given me any enlightenment. If you could point out what I've done wrong I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Create the text file again, use a debugger to check the value of a (independent from the output)

Comment: Check the file properly. Code should work fine.

Comment: is it printing `528` or `528...`? My guess is that the file is not in the right folder

Comment: I don't see *any* **error handling**. consequently, you won't know what went wrong.

Comment: Olayinka - Sorry, I see the way I typed it was confusing. I edited to post to be clear. The vlaue 528 is printed out. The inputFile.txt is in the same directory as the source code and application

Thanks all, I will try these suggestions

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

Comment: What is the content of the input file and what happens when you completely change it?

Comment: Other than lack of error-checking, there is nothing seriously wrong with the code. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/988cd27144610209). The problem is probably in the environment (i.e. wrong working directory).

Comment: Shimon - The input file only contains the value 5. The output is always 528 regardless of what I change it to. I even completely deleted "inputFile.txt" from the directory and the code still output 528, though this time it did give me a file not found error

Comment: Q: What is your platform?  Compiler?  Q: Are you using an IDE (e.g. MSVS or Eclipse/CDT)?

Comment: FoggyDay - I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit w/ Service Pack 1. I'm using Dev-C++ (instructor directed) for my editing and compiling

Comment: what editor are you using to generate inputFile.txt ?  I have a suspicion: 28 is ascii for File seperator

Comment: If you type `dir inputFile.txt` from an appropriate command prompt, what size is the file?  Specifically, is the file larger than one byte?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everyone. I ended up starting a new project from scratch and even though I typed in the exact code you see above it decided to work this time. I'm not really sure what to take from this except for sometimes starting over might flush out some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong with your code. I ran it exactly as is on my PC and it worked 100%.

Possible problems:

- You have the file stored in the wrong place
- The file isn't named properly
- The file actually contains "528"
- Your IDE is experiencing some glitch